# Put contents of array all at once

Tags: ruby

I don't understand why this won't do what the title states.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby


require 'socket'
require 'timeout'


class Scanner


def initialize(host, port)
@host = host
@port = port
end


def popen
begin
  array = []

  sock = Socket.new(:INET, :STREAM)
  sockaddr = Socket.sockaddr_in(@port, @host)

  Timeout::timeout(5) do
    array.push("Port #{@port}: Open") if sock.connect(sockaddr)
  end

  puts array

rescue Timeout::Error
  puts "Port #{@port}: Filtered"
rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED
end
  end

end # end Scanner


def main
  begin
    p = 1

case ARGV[0]
when '-p'
  eport = ARGV[1]
  host = ARGV[2]
else
  eport = 65535
  host = ARGV[0]
end

t1 = Time.now

puts "\n"
puts "-" * 70
puts "Scanning #{host}..."
puts "-" * 70

while p <= eport.to_i do
  scan = Scanner.new(host, p)
  scan.popen
  p += 1
end

t2 = Time.now
time = t2 - t1
puts "\nScan completed: #{host} scanned in #{time} seconds."

rescue Errno::EHOSTUNREACH
  puts "This host appears to be unreachable"
rescue Interrupt
  puts "onnection terminated."
end
end


main
```

What I'm trying to achieve is an output similar to nmap, in the way that it scans everything, and then shows all open or closed ports at the end. Instead what happens is that it prints them out as it discovers them. I figured pushing the output into an array then printing the array would achieve such an output, yet it still prints out the ports one at a time. Why is this happening?

Also, I apologize for the formatting, the code tags are a little weird.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop calls `popen` once per iteration. Your `popen` method sets `array = []` each time it is called, then populates it with one item, then you print it with `puts`. On the next loop iteration, you reset `array` to `[]` and do it all again.

You only asked "why," but – you could solve this by setting `array` just once in the body of `main` and then passing it to `popen` (or any number of ways).

Comment: Thanks I guess I could see why it's working the way it is. I've tried creating the empty array in main and then pushing scan.popen into the array but that produced weird and undesired results. I guess I'll just have to figure it out.